# How to append two value to one key using Redis Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data-redis

I using redis caching my project but i have a problem. I had model student and write method put it to redis.First method i write findStudent one week and put it to cache.

```
public void findStudentOneWeek(List<Student> students1) {
    redistemplate.opsForHash().put("Student", student.getId(), List<Customers>);
}
```

Second method I write findStudent one day.

```
public void findStudentOneDay(List<Student> students2) {
    redistemplate.opsForHash().put("Student", student.getId(), List<Customers>);
}
```

But i want total user from 8 day. It mean i want hold one key **Student** but new value equal total value method **findStudentOneWeek** + total value method **findStudentOneDay**. But i don't now how to do. I can't find method working it. I know method put from redis but it remove old value and save new value. I don't want it. I want value total.

Comment: It mean: I want total value from two method redis using one key. If i using put it remove old value(value from one week) and add new value(value from one day). Total i only have value one day. I want value 8 day.

Comment: so in simple you want one key with multiple values right? why don't you try list in redis caching ?

Comment: Yes. How to work it. Please share me some example. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I assume a typo, where `List<Customers>` should be `List<Students> student`:

```
redistemplate.opsForHash().put("Student", student.getId(), List<Students> students);
```

Spring Data class [`HashOperations`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-keyvalue/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/keyvalue/redis/core/HashOperations.html) works on the similar principle as [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). Both allow you to get the value by the key (and the hash key in case of `HashOperations`). Read the current value `List<Customers>` and put them with a new value to the template.

```
List<Students> students = redistemplate.opsForHash().get("Student", student.getId());
students2.addAll(students);
redistemplate.opsForHash().put("Student", student.getId(), students2);
```

Comment: Thank you. I have question. What diferent key vs hashKey.And when I using key when i using hashKey